# How do I format <select> tags and <form> tags in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is my current layout
[image]

And I am trying to figure out how to have all of the information "inline" like the following

[image]

I've never worked with forms before so I have no idea how to format it, I tried googling but couldn't come up with any useful information because every example only had  tag instead of multiple like my example

Comment: Where's your code? Put it on fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/48nLnqop/

Comment: use table for that

Comment: @chirag Okay thanks will give it a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use without `table` like this.

```css
li label {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><label for="name">First Name:</label></li>
<li><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
table th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th width="50%" align="left">Firstname</th>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

you can use `<table>` format in HTML
Look [w3schools basic tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) for further detailed information.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <td><input...></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <td><input...></td>
  </tr>     
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all add  tag to your text. Then give your labels and select a fixed width, you might also need to set them with display:inline-block:

```
label{
width: 150px;
display:inline-block
}
select {
width:100px;
display:inline-block
}
```

Here is a modification with the first column of fields: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3d4b45zg/)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try to put everything in a table, like this:

```css
td {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <lable>First Name</lable>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <lable>Last Name</lable>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td width="50%">First Name*</td>
    <td width="50%"><input style="width:100%;"/></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
    <td >Last Name*</td>
    <td><input style="width:100%;"/></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
    <td >Street Name*</td>
    <td ><input style="width:100%;"/></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
    <td >City</td>
    <td ><input style="width:75%;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td >State</td>
    <td ><input style="width:50%;"/></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
    <td >Zip</td>
    <td ><input style="width:65%;"/></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
    <td >Phone</td>
    <td ><input style="width:70%;"/></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    
    
    <table>
    
        <tr>
    <td width="50%">Processor Speed</td>
    <td width="50%"><select style="width:100%"><option></option><option>2.4GHz</option></select></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
    <td >Memory</td>
    <td><select style="width:100%"><option></option><option>1GB</option></select></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
    <td >Monitor size</td>
    <td ><select style="width:100%"><option></option><option>15"</option></select></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
    <td >Hard Drive</td>
    <td ><select style="width:100%"><option></option><option>240GB</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td >Dvd Burner</td>
    <td>
    <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <tr>
    <td align="right" width="20%"><input type="checkbox" style="width:75%"/></td>
    <td align="left" width="30%">yes</td>
   <td align="right" width="20%"><input type="checkbox" style="width:75%"/></td>
    <td align="left" width="30%">NO</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td >LAN Card</td>
    <td>
    <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <tr>
    <td align="right" width="20%"><input type="checkbox" style="width:75%"/></td>
    <td align="left" width="30%">yes</td>
   <td align="right" width="20%"><input type="checkbox" style="width:75%"/></td>
    <td align="left" width="30%">NO</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>    <tr>
    <td >Media Card Reader</td>
    <td>
    <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <tr>
    <td align="right" width="20%"><input type="checkbox" style="width:75%"/></td>
    <td align="left" width="30%">yes</td>
   <td align="right" width="20%"><input type="checkbox" style="width:75%"/></td>
    <td align="left" width="30%">NO</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    
       
    
    
    </table>
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td width="50%">First Name*</td>
<td width="50%"><input style="width:100%;"/></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td width="50%">Last Name*</td>
<td width="50%"><input style="width:100%;"/></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td width="50%">Street Name*</td>
<td width="50%"><input style="width:100%;"/></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td width="50%">City</td>
<td width="50%"><input style="width:75%;"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%">State</td>
<td width="50%"><input style="width:50%;"/></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td width="50%">Zip</td>
<td width="50%"><input style="width:65%;"/></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
<td width="50%">Phone</td>
<td width="50%"><input style="width:70%;"/></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: in the same way you can arrange the other shown layout also if you want i will post  the other !

Comment: copy the code and just change the <input />  ....to <select></select> you can understand

Answer (score 0):

you can layout in table

```
<table  border="0" cellspacing="20">
 <tr >
  <td >Processor Speed</td>
  <td><select><option>2.4GHz</option></select></td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
  <td >Memory</td>
  <td><select><option>1 GB</option></select></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#contact-wrap{}

#contact-wrap { border: 1px solid black; font-family: arial, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-spacing: 0px;}
#contact-wrap, #contact-wrap th, #contact-wrap td { border-collapse: collapse;  vertical-align:top;}
#contact-wrap td, #contact-wrap th { text-align: left; padding: 0px; }
#contact-wrap input[type="text"] { width: 100%; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; }
```

```html
<table id="contact-wrap">
    <colgroup>
     <col style="width:50%">
     <col style="width:50%">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <h4>Contact Information</h4>
         <table id="contact-info">
                <colgroup>
                    <col style="width:40%">
                    <col style="width:60%">
                </colgroup>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name: *</td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name: *</td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Street: *</td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>City: *</td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" style="width:70%" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>State: *</td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" style="width:60%" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zip: *</td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" style="width:55%" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone: *</td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" style="width:70%" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
         <h4>Computer Cofiguration</h4>
         <table id="config-info">
                <colgroup>
                 <col style="width:50%">
                 <col style="width:50%">
                </colgroup>
                <tr>
                    <td>Processor Speed: *</td>
                    <td>
                     <select>
                         <option>3.2 GH</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Memory: *</td>
                    <td>
                     <select>
                         <option>1 GB</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Monitor Size: *</td>
                    <td>
                     <select>
                         <option>16"</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hard Drive: *</td>
                    <td>
                     <select>
                         <option>240 GB</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>DVD Burner: *</td>
                    <td>
                     <input type="radio" name="yes">
                        <label for="yes">Yes</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="no">
                        <label for="yes">No</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>LAN Card: *</td>
                    <td>
                     <input type="radio" name="yes">
                        <label for="yes">Yes</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="no">
                        <label for="yes">No</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Media Card Reader: *</td>
                    <td>
                     <input type="radio" name="yes">
                        <label for="yes">Yes</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="no">
                        <label for="yes">No</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**The code is here.**

```css
#contact-info { border: 1px solid black; font-family: arial, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-spacing: 0px; }

#contact-info, #contact-info th, #contact-info td { border-collapse: collapse;}
#contact-info td, #contact-info th { text-align: left; padding: 8px;}
#contact-info input{ width:70%; height:20px; line-height:20px;}
```

```html
<table id="contact-info">
<colgroup>
    <col style="width:40%">
    <col style="width:60%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name: *</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last Name: *</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Street: *</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>City: *</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" style="width:30%" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>State: *</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" style="width:20%" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zip: *</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" style="width:25%" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Phone: *</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="" style="width:30%" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using flexbox, but it may not be too compatible with older versions of IE (people looking for new computers)

With this option you will want to wrap your input titles (name, city, etc.) with a div.

```
form {
  box-sizing : border-box;
  margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing : border-box; /* allows calculating size percentages without border and padding interfering */
  background-color: green;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing : border-box;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

li div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 40%;
}
li div::after { /* a pseudo element for a spacer */ 
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

input {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/48nLnqop/3/

may want to remove the background colours from the example, unless you're having an early christmas special.